# NodeJS Entries wait finish each element

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have this piece of code that cycle some element,
I need to wait the function will and before cycle to next element,
now all elements are spreaded rapidly before finish.

How can I solve that?

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(config)) {
            console.log('Check: ' + value.name);

            const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

            // Wait to finish this Function below before cycle to next Element
            (async () => {
                         // inside this got some await
```

Comment: Call your logic out side of `(async () => {`.

Answer (score 0):

```
const someAsyncActionWithElement = async (element) => {
         // Magic here
}

const someFunc = async () => {
   for (const element of elements) {
      await someAsyncActionWithElement(element)
   }         
}
```

Comment: As this may or may not be the answer, please describe why/how this will help as an answer to the question

Comment: @Svenmarim this code does exactly what author is asking about)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @mufazmi if someone asks you 2 + 2, do you usually explain how and/or why does it work and why the answer is 4? If you have any particular question about the code I posted, then I will gladly answer)